# Posting form data to twitter as tweet

Tags: twitter

I'm just wondering whether its possible to be able to post data easily from a form built in my website to Twitter and post as a users tweet through their account?

I have a form field that I get people to enter some text. Upon hitting submit on my form, I want another step to happen where the content they have submitted is placed in another text field, with a twitter hashtag added. The user is then presented with twitter log in form and upon hitting 'post' I want it to tweet the content to the users twitter.

Is this possible? Basically what I am trying to achieve is for the tweet and login to twitter step be more integrated in my user journey, and if possible with as much of my sites theming as possible rather than loading the twitter site to log in and tweet...

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance